# Confused with object references

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am preparing myself to the Java certification and confused with object references in this case.
In this piece of code I can't understand why ArrayList's and arrays's elements aren't affected when we assign a new object to them?

```
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> myArrList = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("Jan");
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("Feb");
    myArrList.add(sb1);
    myArrList.add(sb2);

    StringBuilder[] array = myArrList.toArray(new StringBuilder[2]);
    for(StringBuilder val : array) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }

    StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder("NNN");
    sb2 = sb3;

    for(StringBuilder val : array) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }

    for(StringBuilder val : myArrList) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
```

Output:

```
Jan
Feb
Jan
Feb
Jan
Feb
```

I will be grateful if you could provide simple explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References are pointers. Assigning a new value to a variable consists in making this pointer point to another object. So, at the beginning, you have an array with two elements:

```
array[0] ---> Jan <--- sb1
array[1] ---> Feb <--- sb2
```

Then you create another StringBuilder, referenced by sb3:

```
array[0] ---> Jan <--- sb1
array[1] ---> Feb <--- sb2
sb3 --------> NNN
```

Then you say that the sb2 variable should reference the same object as the sb3 variable:

```
array[0] ---> Jan <--- sb1
array[1] ---> Feb 
sb3 --------> NNN <--- sb2
```

As you're seeing, array[0] and array[1] still reference the same objects Jan and Feb.